# MLModel works with MultiArray output but cannot successfully change the output to an image

Tags: python, keras, coreml, coremltools, mlmodel

I have converted a Keras model to a MLModel using coremltools 4.0 with limited success.

It works but only if I use an MLMultiArray for the output and covert to an image. Converting to an image takes magnitudes longer than inferencing; making it unusable.

If I try to change the MLModel spec to use images for output I get this error running prediction:

> Failed to convert output Identity to image:
>
> NSUnderlyingError=0x2809bad00 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Invalid array shape (
> 2048,
> 2048,
> 3
> ) for converting to gray image"

Even though I have specified *RGB* for the output color:

> output {
> name: "Identity"
> type {
> imageType {
> width: 2048
> height: 2048
> colorSpace: **RGB**
> }
> }
> }

If I use a MultiArray (that works) Xcode reports:

> output: Float32 1 x 2048 x 2048 x 3 array

I suspect the issue is the first dimension, which is the batch number but no dimensions are shown, so I can't delete the batch dimension:

> output {
> name: "Identity"
> type {
> multiArrayType {
> dataType: FLOAT32
> }
> }
> }

I don't think I can just add an output shape to the Keras Conv2D output layer because it has multiple inbound nodes with different shapes. Here are the output shapes:

```
>>> print(outputLayer.get_output_shape_at(0))
(None, None, None, 3)
>>> print(outputLayer.get_output_shape_at(1))
(1, 512, 512, 3)
>>> print(outputLayer.get_output_shape_at(2))
(1, 2048, 2048, 3)

>>> print(outputLayer.output)
Tensor("SR/Identity:0", shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=float32)
```

I think coremltools is confusing the batch for the channels that is why it is attempting to create a grayscale image even if I specify RGB.

Any idea how to fix it?

I have the original Keras model, but I don't see how specify shapes without a batch dimension.
Here is the beginning and ending of the Keras model layer description

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
LR_input (InputLayer)           [(None, None, None,  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Pre_blocks_conv (Conv2D)        multiple             896         LR_input[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
F_1_1_1 (Conv2D)                multiple             9248        Pre_blocks_conv[0][0]            

...                             multiple
...                             multiple

SR (Conv2D)                     multiple             84          PixelShuffle[0][0]               
==================================================================================================
```

Comment: You can find the answer to your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048582/coremltools-cannot-successfully-change-the-output-to-an-image

Comment: You can also find the answer that I accepted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Core ML the order of the dimensions is (channels, height, width) so it expects to see a 3 x 2048 x 2048 output instead of 2048 x 2048 x 3.

Note that you also need to make sure the output pixels are in the range [0, 255] instead of [0, 1] which is probably what your Keras model gives you.

Comment: Thanks Matthijs! I thought it was something like that. Any suggestions how to change it to what Core ML is expecting? Do I need a helper function or something to output in the range of 0-255?

Comment: For putting the channels on the correct axis, it might be something that the pixelshuffle layer does "wrong" (from the point of view of Core ML). For output to the range 0-255, it depends on what the current output is. For [0, 1], just add a multiply layer at the end (easiest to do this in the Keras model). For [-1, 1], you need two layers: add 1 and multiply by 127.5.